# How to remove a user from AWS Cognito using adminDeleteUser() method?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

everyone.
First of all, thanks for your consideration.
Now I am building a web application using Node.js and hosted by AWS.
And I am using user management functionalities of AWS cognito.
All functions of creating and reading is possible there, awesome!
But when I wanna remove a user from Cognito, I faced some issues.
The official document of AWS Cognito tells me to use deleteUser() of adminDeleteUser().
I used deleteUser(). The parameter of this method is AccessToken of current user - me.
But I wanna delete not me but the others. I am managing users via AWS Cognito.
So deleteUser() can't be my choice.
So I faced the adminDeleteUser(). This method's parameter is user_id and I can get this value from AWS Cognito user pool. But this function need some authority.
When I asked chatGPT it answered me :

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-west-2' }); // Set the appropriate region

const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

const params = {
  UserPoolId: 'YOUR_USER_POOL_ID',
  Username: 'USER_USERNAME',
};

cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminDeleteUser(params, function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('User deleted successfully');
  }
});
```

It's important to note that the adminDeleteUser() method requires developer credentials, which means you need to have appropriate AWS access keys and secret keys configured to authenticate the request.

But I can't understand what AWS access keys and secret keys.
I already have AWS_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID, AWS_COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID in my .env file.
It seems not enough for that keys to use adminDeleteUser() method.

If you know about the AWS access keys please let me know.
Thanks...

What AWS access keys needed for adminDeleteUser() in AWS Cognito

Comment: Where are you going to run this application if its on ec2 make sure you give the instance role all the necessary permissions and the aws sdk will pick up the correct permissions. If you run on any other machine set the AWS profile to get those details.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Vikram. Then I am new at AWS and participating a project.
Could you give me detailed question plz?
live:.cid.2b829538acc9175

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [AdminDeleteUser Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminDeleteUser.html), this API requires IAM credentials for invocation: the access key and secret key refer to them.

There are [many ways to provide credentials to the AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html), but the recommended method when implementing on an EC2 VM or in a Lambda function is to use a properly configured service role.

> Here are the ways you can supply your credentials in order of
> recommendation:
>
> 1. Loaded from AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) roles for
>    Amazon EC2
> 2. Loaded from the shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials)
> 3. Loaded from environment variables
> 4. Loaded from a JSON file on disk
> 5. Other credential-provider classes provided by the JavaScript SDK